# Single level of abstraction

Tags: delphi, object-pascal

I am reading the "Clean Code" book and trying refactoring my source code according to the principles "single level of abstraction"/"separation of concerns".

How would you refactor the following code? I am interested in the details like:

- How would you separate the abstraction levels?
- How many classes would you create?
- How would you name the new classes?
- How would maybe rename the existing class?
- Other things...?

```pas
TConditionsUtils = class(TObject)
public
  function GetPolungType(const APolung: String): TPolung;
  function GetPolungTypeName(const APolungType: TPolung): String;
  function GetPolungTypeOfCondition(const AConditionName: String; const AConditions: IGenericList<ICondition>): TPolung;
  function GetPolungTypeNameOfCondition(const AConditionName: String; const AConditions: IGenericList<ICondition>): String;

  function GetBoardType(const ABoardType: String): TBoardType;
  function GetBoardTypeName(const ABoardType: TBoardType): String;
  function GetBoardTypeOfCondition(const AConditionName: String; const AConditions: IGenericList<ICondition>): TBoardType;
  function GetBoardTypeNameOfCondition(const AConditionName: String; const AConditions: IGenericList<ICondition>): String;
end;
```

For more understanding what the functions do you can check the following code:

- literals beginning with c_ are text constants
- TBoardType and TPolung are enumerated types
- The defined functions are doing nothing else determining from a text a datatype and vice versa
- The function `GetPolungTypeNameOfCondition` and `GetBoardTypeOfCondition` search for a conditionname in the list and return either a name of the type or an enumarated type

```pas
TBoardType = (bt_Unknown = 0, bt_D = 1, bt_K = 2, bt_L = 3, bt_HP = 4);
TPolung = (pUnknown = 0, pCommon_N = 1, pCommon_P = 2);

function TConditionsUtils.GetPolungType(const APolung: String): TPolung;
begin
  if SameText(APolung, c_Polung_commonN) then
    Result := pCommon_N
  else if SameText(APolung, c_Polung_commonP) then
    Result := pCommon_P
  else
    Result := pUnknown;
end;

function TConditionsUtils.GetPolungTypeName(const APolungType: TPolung): String;
begin
  case APolungType of
    pCommon_N: Result := c_Polung_commonN;
    pCommon_P: Result := c_Polung_commonP;
  else
    Result := c_Unknown;
  end;
end;    

function TConditionsUtils.GetBoardType(const ABoardType: String): TBoardType;
begin
  if SameText(ABoardType, c_BoardType_D) then
    Result := bt_D
  else if SameText(ABoardType, c_BoardType_K) then
    Result := bt_K
  else if SameText(ABoardType, c_BoardType_L) then
    Result := bt_L
  else if SameText(ABoardType, c_BoardType_HP) then
    Result := bt_HP
  else
    Result := bt_Unknown;
end;    

function TConditionsUtils.GetBoardTypeName(const ABoardType: TBoardType): String;
begin
  case ABoardType of
    bt_D: Result := c_BoardType_D;
    bt_K: Result := c_BoardType_K;
    bt_L: Result := c_BoardType_L;
    bt_HP: Result := c_BoardType_HP;
  else
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: To make it easier for us to understand your code, and what the best option is for you, I would recommend adding more code. Can you show the declaration of `TBoardType` and the other methods related to `TBoardType` ?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing languages. "Polung" sounds German, the rest sounds English. Keep your names consistent.

Comment: Yes, it's a german word which I got from the client. But, you are right, I have to keep the names consistent.